# Laravel 5 cannot update relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've been trying for countless hours now, but still having issues updating a models relationship, the closest I've got to is a 'Method fill does not exist.' error.

Listing model:

```
 class Listing extends Model
    {       
        protected $fillable = [
            'uid', 'start_date',...........
        ];     

        public function locations()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\ListingLocation');
        }        
    }
```

Location (relationship to listing - hasMany):

```
class ListingLocation extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'listing_id', 'location',
    ];

    public function listing()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Listing');
    }
}
```

This returns my model and relationship, which I can view with dd($listing)

```
$listing = Listing::with('locations')->findOrFail($id);
```

This will update my listing model, which I can see the changes after calling dd($listing) again

```
$listing->fill($array);
```

However when I attempt to fill the relationship as per below, I get 'Method fill does not exist.'

```
$listing->locations->fill($array['locations']);
```

How can I update the relationship successfully before calling $listing->push();?

Comment: `Locations` is a `hasMany` relationship, so it will return a collection, not a single model. You'll have to pick a location to update.

Comment: I think you are looking for sync method: `$listing->locations()->sync($array['locations']);`

Comment: As this is a one-to-many relationship, sync doesn't work correct? When calling sync I get an error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::sync()

Answer (score 2):

Change your location to a single record, not a collection

For example:

```
$listings->locations->first()->fill($array['locations']);
```

to fill every record use foreach

```
@foreach($listings->locations as $location)
$location->fill(do_something);
@endforeach
```

Comment: This also doesn't seem to work as this is attempting to fill an array of locations in the first record. Even if I update it to .....->fill($array['locations'][0]); it still doesn't update the attributes when doing a dump and die

Comment: Also noting if i use update instead of fill, this works however I want to overwrite all locations for that model and not just the first one. Sync seems like what I want but not sure that it works with one-to-many relationships

Comment: I've updated my answer, sync is suitable for many to many... not one to many

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new class to extend hasMany which allowed me to use sync as per alexweissman at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/syncing-one-to-many-relationships.

Extract from forum:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

/**
 * @link https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.php
 */
class HasManySyncable extends HasMany
{
    public function sync($data, $deleting = true)
    {
        $changes = [
            'created' => [], 'deleted' => [], 'updated' => [],
        ];

        $relatedKeyName = $this->related->getKeyName();

        // First we need to attach any of the associated models that are not currently
        // in the child entity table. We'll spin through the given IDs, checking to see
        // if they exist in the array of current ones, and if not we will insert.
        $current = $this->newQuery()->pluck(
            $relatedKeyName
        )->all();

        // Separate the submitted data into "update" and "new"
        $updateRows = [];
        $newRows = [];
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            // We determine "updateable" rows as those whose $relatedKeyName (usually 'id') is set, not empty, and
            // match a related row in the database.
            if (isset($row[$relatedKeyName]) && !empty($row[$relatedKeyName]) && in_array($row[$relatedKeyName], $current)) {
                $id = $row[$relatedKeyName];
                $updateRows[$id] = $row;
            } else {
                $newRows[] = $row;
            }
        }

        // Next, we'll determine the rows in the database that aren't in the "update" list.
        // These rows will be scheduled for deletion.  Again, we determine based on the relatedKeyName (typically 'id').
        $updateIds = array_keys($updateRows);
        $deleteIds = [];
        foreach ($current as $currentId) {
            if (!in_array($currentId, $updateIds)) {
                $deleteIds[] = $currentId;
            }
        }

        // Delete any non-matching rows
        if ($deleting && count($deleteIds) > 0) {
            $this->getRelated()->destroy($deleteIds);

            $changes['deleted'] = $this->castKeys($deleteIds);
        }

        // Update the updatable rows
        foreach ($updateRows as $id => $row) {
            $this->getRelated()->where($relatedKeyName, $id)
                 ->update($row);
        }

        $changes['updated'] = $this->castKeys($updateIds);

        // Insert the new rows
        $newIds = [];
        foreach ($newRows as $row) {
            $newModel = $this->create($row);
            $newIds[] = $newModel->$relatedKeyName;
        }

        $changes['created'][] = $this->castKeys($newIds);

        return $changes;
    }


    /**
     * Cast the given keys to integers if they are numeric and string otherwise.
     *
     * @param  array  $keys
     * @return array
     */
    protected function castKeys(array $keys)
    {
        return (array) array_map(function ($v) {
            return $this->castKey($v);
        }, $keys);
    }

    /**
     * Cast the given key to an integer if it is numeric.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $key
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function castKey($key)
    {
        return is_numeric($key) ? (int) $key : (string) $key;
    }
}
```

You can then override Eloquent's hasMany method in your model class:

```
 /**
     * Overrides the default Eloquent hasMany relationship to return a HasManySyncable.
     *
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function hasMany($related, $foreignKey = null, $localKey = null)
    {
        $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);

        $foreignKey = $foreignKey ?: $this->getForeignKey();

        $localKey = $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName();

        return new HasManySyncable(
            $instance->newQuery(), $this, $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey, $localKey
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get all of a user's phone numbers.
     */
    public function phones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Phone');
    }
```

A sync method will now be available to any hasMany relationships you have on this model:

```
$user->phones()->sync([
    [
    'id' => 21,
        'label' => "primary",
        'number' => "5555551212"
    ],
    [
    'id' => null,
        'label' => "mobile",
        'number' => "1112223333"
    ]
]);
```